# EntityFramework 6.2.0 проблемы с выполнением запросов

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, entity-framework

Мы используем связку (клиент WPF) -> EF 6.2.0 -> (MS SQL сервер). Процессы все отлажены, работает хорошо.
Но в отдельных единичных случаях, на единичных машинах (windows 10,7) при запросах вылетает исключение, которое я никак не могу устранить. Естественно, отловить у себя в отладке не выходит.
Привожу текст сообщения исключения:

> Было выведено исключение, скорее всего связанное с временной ошибкой.
>   При подключении к базе данных SQL Azure рекомендуется использовать
>   SqlAzureExecutionStrategy.

Но мы не используем SQL Azure.

Иногда эта проблема решалась полной переустановкой на используемой машине фреймворка (работаем с 4.6.1). Но в отдельных случаях такой подход не нес никакого положительного эффекта, и каждый запрос к базе продолжал сопровождаться указанной ошибкой.
Что также странно, периодически проблема пропадает, но потом появляется снова.

Подскажите, чем лечить, в какую сторону смотреть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А строка подключения там нормальная?

Comment: Да, строка та, что нужно.
 Удалось найти промежуточное решение...собственно, ответ крылся в самой ошибке.
 public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public MyConfiguration()
        {
            SetExecutionStrategy(
                "System.Data.SqlClient",
                () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy(60, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
        }
    }

Однако, иногда, все ровно вылетает. Такое впечатление, что какие-то проблемы с подключением у клиентов. И даже вот этих выставленных 60-ти попыток не всегда хватает. Но стало легче, теперь хоть так работает.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyConfiguration()
    {
        SetExecutionStrategy(
            "System.Data.SqlClient",
            () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy(60, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
    }
}
```

Данный блок, помещенный в проект (я разместил в одном файле с главной viewmodel, но как разные классы), частично решает проблему. Но периодически вылеты в виде исключений проявляются.